# Mongoose timing out on Model.InsertMany(); databases not showing up on the MongoDB shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have node v14.17.6, MongoDB 5.0 and mongoose 5.13.8 (old version).
My app.js:

```
//0. setup
const express = require("express");
//require module date.js, which binds exports to const date
// const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

//console.log(date()); what i exported from the date.js module

const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); //alt to body parser
app.use(express.static("public")); //static files are in the "public" folder
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //set app view engine to EJS

//use mongo and mongoose instead of arrays to store data

//a) connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27107/todolistDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

//b) create schema
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String
});

//c) create model
const Item = mongoose.model('item', itemsSchema);

//d) create documents
const item1 = new Item({
  name: "wake up (8 am)"
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "cry (8:30 am - 12 pm)"
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "listen to “sexyback” on loop (12 pm - 7 pm)"
});

const item4 = new Item({
  name: "punch a hole in the wall and patch it up (7 pm - 7:30 pm)"
});

const item5 = new Item({
  name: "sleep (8 pm)"
});

//e) put docs into array
const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];

//f) instert items into collection
Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(e){
if (e) {
  console.log(e);
} else {
  console.log("congration you done it");
}
});

//1. regular list
app.get("/", function(req,res) {

//we call function that's bound to const date and we activate getDate()
// const day = date.getDate(); //variable day is bound to the output of the date module

//render file called views/list.ejs, and send it a variable called listTitle, whose value is "day"
res.render("list", { //uses view engine to render a particular page (views/list.ejs)
  listTitle: "my daily routine",
  newListItems: items
});

}); //app.get()

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const item = req.body.nextItem; //the item user inputs in the form

  if (req.body.list === "Work list") {
    workItems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/work");
  } else { //req.body.list === the current day
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
    //when post request is triggered on /, we log the value of item
    //and redirect to / which gets us to app.get()
    //which will render list.ejs with both variables
  }
  console.log(req.body.list);
}); //app.post()


//2. work list
app.get("/work", function(req, res){
  res.render("list", {
    listTitle: "Work list",
    newListItems: workItems
  });
}); //app.get()

app.post("/work", function(req, res){
  const item = req.body.nextItem;
  workItems.push(item);
  res.redirect("/work");
}); //app.post

//3. about page
app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
}); //app.get()

//3. spinning up server
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("EJS");
}); //app.listen()
```

here's the message that shows up on my terminal when i execute 'node app.js':

```
$ node app.js
EJS
MongooseError: Operation `items.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
        at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\toDoList-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:198:23)
        at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
        at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
      insertedDocs: [
        { _id: 6135276e4595e61b748e4381, name: 'wake up (8 am)', __v: 0 },
        {
          _id: 6135276e4595e61b748e4382,
          name: 'cry (8:30 am - 12 pm)',
          __v: 0
        },
        {
          _id: 6135276e4595e61b748e4383,
          name: 'listen to “sexyback” on loop (12 pm - 7 pm)',
          __v: 0
        },
        {
          _id: 6135276e4595e61b748e4384,
          name: 'punch a hole in the wall and patch it up (7 pm - 7:30 pm)',
          __v: 0
        },
        { _id: 6135276e4595e61b748e4385, name: 'sleep (8 pm)', __v: 0 }
      ]
    }
    (node:7028) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27107
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\toDoList-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:846:32)
        at C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\toDoList-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
        at C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\toDoList-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\toDoList-v2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
```

I am running mongod and mongo in separate tabs. Both work fine, but when I use "show dbs" command in mongo, I don't get this new todolistDB database that I created.

I formatted my computer and lost all my programs and installations. This sort of code used to work.
Now I had to add a PATH to MongoDB in order for it to start working, but I don't remember how to do the same for mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 27107 instead of 27017.